# how to download another website file into my website?

Tags: screen-scraping

hi I have a domain.com website and I was wondering how would I download a file with simple url into my website space ? is it using shell scripts or what ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the tools you have available on the web server. If you have ssh access, and either wget or curl is installed on the server, then that would be the easiest way: ssh into the server, and the issue a command like this:

```
wget http://example.com/resource
```

If you don't have ssh access, you'll need to write a script in whatever scripting language you have available on the server, make sure it's properly protected, and then run it.

Answer (score 1):

use [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) or [wget for windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm)

Answer (score 0):

That completely depends on what kind of access you have to the server.

When you have shell access, for example you could do a simple `wget <url>` to download a file, and then you would just move it to the correct location.

Otherwise, if it is shared hosting and you only have ftp access, you can put a script on the server you can executes that then downloads a remote file.